# date format yyyy-mm-dd to dd-M-yy

Tags: javascript, jquery, date-format

I have one date string and the string having date format yyyy-mm-dd. I want to change the date format to dd-M-yy. Can any one suggest me how I can change dynamically at run time also I have attaching my code .

```
function(){
  var date1 = Dashboards.getParameterValue("date").toString(); 
  alert(date1)
  document.getElementById('render_SelectDate').value=date1;
}
or
function(){
    var date = Dashboards.getParameterValue("parDate").toString();
    var date1=date.format("dd-M-yy");

  alter(date1)

 document.getElementById('render_SelectDate').value=date1;
}
```

i can't get any success so far i can't use any external js in my application ..so plz suggest me

Comment: possible duplicate of [change the date string format in dd-M-yy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28249936/change-the-date-string-format-in-dd-m-yy)

Comment: You should not ask twice the same question. If you do not get an answer, edit your question to make it more clear.

Comment: Hi Lorenz..Sorry for that ..next time onwards that will not happen again ..

Comment: i have put the answer below ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this :

```
  var yyyymmdd = '2015-01-31',
      ddMyy = yyyymmdd.replace (/(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)/, 
                function (_, y, m, d) { 
                  m = '???,Jan,Feb,Mar.Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec '.split (',')[+m];
                  y = y.slice (-2);
                  return [d,m,y].join ('-') });
```

Or as a callable function :

```
function dateConvert (yyyymmdd) {
   return yyyymmdd.replace (/(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)/, 
            function (_, y, m, d) { 
              m = '???,Jan,Feb,Mar.Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec '.split (',')[+m];
              y = y.slice (-2);
              return [d,m,y].join ('-') }) }
```

}

Comment: Hi HBP...Thanks for your reply ..can you please provide me any working example...if possible..i need that out put will be stored in one variable that variable i will pass dynamically in my application ..

Comment: Does the function I added help? Pass it the yyyy-mm-dd format value and it returns the corresponding dd-M-yy

Comment: i have created one parameter in my application as name abc.the parameter will be getting dynamically value at the rum time in yyyy-mm-dd format.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format
might be helphul

Comment: Hi Simon..Thanks for your reply ..i have already look this link but can't get any success so far ...if possible plz suggest any other method..

Answer (score 0):

this is the answer:
var formatted = $.datepicker.formatDate("dd-Y-mm", new Date("01-JAN-15"));

Here put the date as per your required format